# What is the difference between - socket.broadcast.emit() and io.to(socketID).emit()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Getting started with using socket.io library. There is this use case where I need to broadcast to all connected clients except the sender. Therefore, I had used the **socket.broadcast.emit()**.

I came across another technique to achieve the same which was **io.to(socketID).emit()**. From what I understand, this method emits to a room with an id = socketID (ideally this room would have just one client by default and the event will be emitted to this client).

**Is there any other functional difference between these two methods or can I use them interchangeably?**

Tried both ways, and they both seemed to work fine. Just wanted to know if there's any difference and any limitations to either way of emitting.

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    setInterval(() => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('dummy_event', 'new_testing_21jan');
    }, 5000);
}
```

and

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    setInterval(() => {
        io.to(socket.id).emit('dummy_event', 'new_testing_21jan');
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**socket.broadcast.emit()** broadcasts an event to all connected clients except the sender.

**io.to(socketID).emit()** is used to send event to specific socket by socket ID.

Both can be used interchangeably in your use case, but **io.to(socketID).emit()** is more specific and useful for emitting events to specific clients.

**socket.broadcast.emit()** wants to send the event to all clients except the sender.

You can use **io.in(roomName).emit()** to send an event to all customers in a particular room.